# I don't see vlc in app store

Tags: appcenter

I don't see vlc or inkscape in the app store.  They are installable with synaptic.  Is this a bug?

It seems that many things are not there.  These apps are standard.

I thought the USA repository was athe problem so I switched to  Using main Ubuntu repo.  The problem is still there.

Eos 5.1

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt update` (from the CLI)? If that does not solve the issue, you may try posting the `apt` configuration files.

Comment: That is a great idea.  What are the files to send when Indo this?

Comment: You may want to try `tree -lah /etc/apt` and update your answer with the result.

Comment: It is working now.  Not sure what went wrong.  I've been using Linux since 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the appCenter has a search input on the topper right corner. Type inside `vlc` or `inkscape` and you will find both of them.

[image: vlc]
[image: inkscape]

Comment: I did.  I am not sure why my friends computer does not have these things.  I just turned him on to this after a win 7 wipe. I cannot remember if my computer has them before adding them.  I want him to use the app store because he is a total newcomer.  I use terminal or synaptic.  My demos on how to add software are not working well since these are standards.

Comment: Probably you have some problem, because as you can see on my screenshots - there are two versions of both of them - the regullar and flatpak also

Comment: Yes my friends machine is a little strange.  I will delete the app and then see if it shows up. It was clearly in the repo and I did search for it after failing to see vlc in audio or video sections.   But I should have grabbed a screenshot.   I've been using Ubuntu derivs since 1212. And I play with things so I have a bit of experience.  And I'm not tweaking his machine because I want it to work long term.  However, it could be the interference with a broken keyboard (with a sticky key) which we disabled.